# How to remove multiple word from grep command in AIX

Tags: grep, lvm, aix

I am trying to check disks used for mirror in lvs. currently I am using "lslv -m ulv" command but to check for multiple lvs is difficult. I guess there should be some option in grep to exclude repetition of word, because if I will grep "disk" it will show a number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

the command that you need is `uniq`.
Supply the output from grep through `uniq`

```
grep disk | uniq
```

---

Update:

```
 ~ > cat test
0001 0201 hdisk0
0002 0202 hdisk0
0003 0203 hdisk0
0004 0204 hdisk0
 ~ > cat test | cut -d " " -f 3 | sort -u
hdisk0
 ~ >
```

I assume you do not need the first two column if the only thing you want to sort by is hdisk0

Comment: Sorry, but It did not work. `lslv -m salvaglv | grep hdisk0 | uniq`. it should give only one row with hdisk0. but insted it gave me same output as `lslv -m salvaglv | grep hdisk0`.

Comment: Ok. Please try to use `sort -u` instead of `uniq`. Also if you could show us the output of `lslv -m salvaglv | grep hdisk0` it could shed some light on by which columns you should sort.

Comment: hemantr:stelsvr> lslv -m salvaglv | grep hdisk0
0001  0201 hdisk0
0002  0202 hdisk0
0003  0203 hdisk0
0004  0204 hdisk0
0005  0205 hdisk0
0006  0206 hdisk0
0007  0207 hdisk0
0008  0208 hdisk0
0009  0209 hdisk0
0010  0210 hdisk0
0011  0211 hdisk0
0012  0212 hdisk0
/u/hemantr                        
hemantr:stelsvr> lslv -m salvaglv | grep hdisk0 | sort -u
0001  0201 hdisk0
0002  0202 hdisk0
0003  0203 hdisk0
0004  0204 hdisk0
0005  0205 hdisk0
0006  0206 hdisk0
0007  0207 hdisk0
0008  0208 hdisk0
0009  0209 hdisk0
0010  0210 hdisk0
0011  0211 hdisk0
0012  0212 hdisk0
/u/hemantr
hemantr:stelsvr>

Comment: i've updated my answer. I assume you do not need the information from first two columns if you want to see only one entry for hdisk0.